# Date importing from oracle to hive using spark hive context format in hive should be YYYYMMDD (dt_skey)

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-spark, hive

I have to import a table from Oracle to Hive using Spark and Scala, date column in Oracle looks like this [Oracle column date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcvJj.png), I have to cast it to the dt_skey format (YYYYMMDD) in Hive. Table format in Hive is Parquet. How can I do that? I googled it a lot but I didn't find any solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems the inputs are in string format, and you need the output also in string format. The INPUT is a big issue. With no further information, what does 16-09-15 mean? 16 September 2015, or 15 September 2016? In Oracle tables you should never store dates as strings - this is just one reason out of many.

Comment: Have you tried using Sqoop?

Comment: YY-MM-DD is the format in oracle, datatype in oracle is DATE, input is in DATE datatype i have to change it to yyyymmdd format and the datatype for that will be int in hive.

Comment: my problem is how can i convert the into yyyymmdd (dt_skey) format in hive.

Comment: @Developer - I have no idea what Hive, Spark etc. are. Are you sure the "dt_skey" must be a string, and not in the "date" datatype? A value in "date" datatype has NO FORMAT - your current dates in Oracle do NOT have the format 16-09-16 IN ORACLE, they are only displayed that way on your screen (by the front-end app you use). Did you try to import the data AS-IS with NO conversion at all? Or do you know for sure you need a string, not a date, datatype in Hive?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input data is supposed to mean yy-mm-dd (so 16-09-15 means year 2016, month 09, day 15) you probably need a transformation like this:

```
select to_char( to_date (dt, 'yy-mm-dd'), 'yyyymmdd') from ...
```

Example:

```
with my_table ( dt ) as ( select '16-09-15' from dual)
  -- this creates a test table my_table with column dt and value as shown
select dt, 
       to_char( to_date (dt, 'yy-mm-dd'), 'yyyymmdd') as dt_skey
from my_table
;


DT        DT_SKEY
--------  --------
16-09-15  20160915
```

You could also manipulate the input string directly but I would strongly recommend against that. Translating to date and back will catch invalid "dates" in your data before you try to push them to an application. Also, the string manipulation would become complicated if the input strings are inconsistent (for example if something like 16-9-15 is allowed along with 16-09-15).

**EDIT**: In a comment to his original question, the OP stated that dt is already in DATE format in Oracle. In that case, it should NOT be wrapped within `to_date()` - that will lead to errors. Rather, the solution is MUCH simpler, all is needed is

`select to_char(dt, 'yyyymmdd') from  ...`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can i know whether this will work in spark ? i'm sure this will work with scoop.

Comment: What is Spark? Also, if you have access to it, can you try? I have no idea what that is.